# Export and import graphcool local data through graphcool cli

Tags: graphql, graphcool

I am trying to export data from a graphcool *local* deployment, so I can import it into another local deployment on my own server. The [documentation](https://docs-next.graph.cool/docs/reference/data-import-and-export/data-export-pa0aip3loh/) suggests using `graphcool export` and `graphcool import` commands. However, trying to run

```
graphcool export -e export.zip -t dev
```

Opens a browser window redirecting me to a console.graph.cool authentication website (cloud deployment). The same happens with the `graphcool import` command

I am in a directory with a *.graphcoolrc* file:

```
targets:
  dev: local/ck4t9gry400040196szky9mr4
  default: dev
```

Is there something else that I need to export using the CLI command? I am sure I am missing some configuration or parameters here, but can't find anything in the docs...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to go to the settings page on your project, click on the authentication tab and get this console command with your token in it.

```
graphcool login --token "supersecrettokenheresdfasdfawerfasdfawefaweafewafdsafsdfasd"
```

after running this you wont be redirected to auth page.

Comment: This works! I just had to add a root token in `graphcool.yml` before.